# =IF(EXACT()) referencing to absolute cell with increasing rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one hefty amount of data, and I need to rearrange it in a form that can be used in ordination analysis.

In data sheet I have the raw data, and on sheet1 I reference to the said data. If a cell N2 in data! exactly matches cell J1 in sheet1!, then it gives value 1, and if false, it gives 0, in cell J2 in sheet1!. This goes on so that in cell K2, cells data!N2 and sheet1!K1 are compared, in L2 cells data!N2 and sheet!L1, and so on. Please see the pic attached for more clarification.

=IF(EXACT(J$1;data!$N$2);1;0)

However, I have some 6 500 rows of data. I would like to write a function/make a macro that increases the to-be-checked row number in data-sheet, so that in cell sheet1!J3 cells data!N3 and sheet!J1 would be compared. I need to somehow get the row number in &N&2 increase with the row numbers of the cells in sheet1.

Thank you already for your help! I suppose it is a rather simple thing, but it feels like I've tried a bit of this and that and still can't make it work.

[a pic of the two sheets and data rearrangement in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CKbh.png)

Comment: Just remove the `$` in front of the `2` in `$N$2` so: `=IF(EXACT(J$1;data!$N2);1;0)`  Now when the formula is copied/dragged down the 2 will change to 3 to 4 to 5 to....

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how come I was such a dumbass and overlooked such a simple thing - must have been staring at the data for way too long, haha.